# Can the source of a JavaScript file loaded into a web-page via a <script> tag be read by other JavaScript in that page?

Tags: javascript, json, security, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm looking at CSRF prevention, and I have a question about a GET URL that returns JSON, and whether or not the data returned by that URL could be accessed via a third-party web-page.

For example, supposing this request

```
GET HTTP 1.1 /rest/foo.js 
Host: myhost.com
```

Returns the dynamically-generated JSON as follows, with a per-session CSRF token:

```js
{user:"My name", userId:1234, CSRFToken: "EFB8765AC2134ACB23486"}
```

Note that this is **not** a JSONP request. Now, suppose I have a web-page at sneakythirdparty.com that reads as follows:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://myhost.com/rest/foo.js" />
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

My question is: Could a script, Flash applet or anything else in the page of a third-party website such as this one read the *source code* of foo.js to obtain the CSRF token?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the `<script>` tag is there for all to see.

For example:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("script");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].hasAttribute('src'))
        console.log(nodes[i].attributes["src"].value);
}
```

Just do a simple XMLHttpRequest to get the source and get the CRSFToken.

**Edit:**

This approach depends on [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) support and relies on the assumption that two requests from the same client (using the same cookies) to myhost.com will respond with the same CRSFToken.

If either of the above do not hold, this approach will not work. If an "external" process (like Flash or Java) have access to the same cookies, they could theoretically mimic the request and get the CSRFToken (assuming the second condition above holds).

Aside from this, if you don't trust the user (or the user's computer), it is possible to grab the CSRFToken from memory, but this seems a bit out of scope for your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply tjameson, but this returns a list of the URLs, and I was asking about to the **source code** of the URL, not the source URL of the script tag - I've updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: That's easy, just use an XMLHttpRequest. Once you have the URL, the rest is trivial. I'm assuming, of course, that two requests to the same URL from the same client will yield the same CRSFToken.

Comment: That's true, but XMLHttpRequest to myhost.com doesn't work from sneakythirdparty.com because of the same-origin policy. My question is, is there some way to circumvent this?

Comment: @Ian Does your myhost.com support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)?

Comment: it does, but using it would enable exactly what I want to ensure is impossible in this case :-)

Comment: @Ian - Updated answer with my assumptions in this approach. I'm not sure how the CRSFToken is being generated, so this is my best guess at a possible attack vector.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26524/discussion-between-ian-and-tjameson)

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to hide your CSRF Token
The all purpose of CSRF Protection is just to make sure that requests to your site actually did come from your site (or other site that you can give them authorization).

So I really don't understand what your are trying to achieve in your example:
If you want to block foo.js from calling from another server you have to obligate people to send the CSRF token when requesting that file, then you check in the server that this token actually match a session key for example set earlier that verifies that user did actually came from your site initially.

If the json {user:"My name", userId:1234, CRSFToken: "EFB8765AC2134ACB23486"} is written in this javascript statically then you are misunderstanding the all concept of CSRF protection.

You have to create the token dynamically according to some user unique data(can be data from the database, can be session id etc...) and then pass the token around your site and block requests to your pages that you want to protect if this token is not valid/exists.

CSRF protection can be done in regular forms and in ajax call - just how you choose it to be

[Good Explanation](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/16/how-to-csrf-protect-all-your-forms/)

Comment: Hi Adidi, the JSON is definitely not static, I agree that would be useless :-) I'll update the question to make that clear. I want to be sure that a CSRF token that's retrieved via a server-side REST call isn't obtainable by a third party.

Comment: Well - the answer is YES! any third party can read javascript files - that is why they called client side files. If you want to block that or control what the json will include eventually - then you need to check who called your file and manipulate it according to it. and a CSRF protection would be great here ! but for that file !

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think it's as clear as that... it's specifically third-party web-pages that I'm asking about. The same-origin policy should stop the file being loaded in third-party web-pages, my question is basically if there's any way around this because it's been loaded via a <script> tag and is JSON.

Comment: Well - you can turn your json file into server file and generate it there. (in the server your only have to define that the response header content type is text/javascript) - then you will have a full control on what the file will return.